# What replaced ListWaveform?

Tags: packages, sound

My old *Mathematica* code used `ListWaveform` to produce a sound file from a table of amplitudes and frequencies; this seems to no longer exist.  What replaced it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This function is still present in version 8, but it is part of the `` Audio` `` package.  For example,

```
<<Audio`
ListWaveform[{{1, 1}, {2, 0.5}}, 440, 1]
```

You can find this information by typing `ListWaveform` into the documentation browser.